# Masonry not working after click in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-masonry, masonry

In my rails app Im trying to implement Masonry. The problem I have is that when I click on the link(Images) Masonry does not work, but if after you click you refresh the page it does work. Any ideas?
Thanks

here is the site: https://salty-waters-72129.herokuapp.com/images

Code:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<head>

<script src="/assets/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/swipebox.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/responsive.css" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)" charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<h1>Listing Images</h1>

 <div id='masonry'>
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
   <%= link_to image.image_url.to_s,class: "swipebox" do %>
    <div class="hov col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="hovereffect">
        <%= image_tag image.image_url.to_s, :class => "img-responsive" %>
          <div class="overlay">
            <h2><%= image.name %></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>
<script src="/assets/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function() {
  var container = document.querySelector('#masonry');
   var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
     columnWidth: '.hov',
     itemSelector: '.hov'
   });
  });
;( function( $ ) {
    $( '.swipebox' ).swipebox();
} )( jQuery );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with masonry, but that the `$(window).load(...)` block doesn't work when you click `Images`.

This is because the `Images` link click is handled with javascript and it doesn't lead to the full page reload, insead it makes an ajax request to the server and replaces the page content. This way `$(window).load()` is not triggered.

Check your [js application code](https://salty-waters-72129.herokuapp.com/assets/application-51eb80cb377dedf45f7fe12894c2c4f6634c874a377381650b45eabc16737cf9.js), the ajax request is sent from the `fetchReplacement = function(url, onLoadFunction, showProgressBar) {...` block.

It looks like this code belongs to the `turbolinks.js`, [here](https://gist.github.com/eliotsykes/07baccff7aff4002723f) is the same code like you have.

If you don't actually need this turbolinks library - just remove it and it should fix the problem. And if you need it - check it's documentation, you should be able to subscribe to the page load event (it does `return triggerEvent(EVENTS.LOAD)` in the ajax response handler) and initialize masonry there.

Comment: @Andy I am glad it helped, consider marking my answer as "accepted", so other people coming here will know that the problem is solved.